# MVC 4 ViewModel unobtrusive validation not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel that I am using to POST data back to the server.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CompanyAdminViewModel))]
public class CompanyAdminViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel User { get; set; }

    public CompanyAdminViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

The Company Entity has child entities: Company.CompanyContacts

```
public class CompanyContact
{
    public int CompanyContactId { get; set; }
    public int JobTitleId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> HireDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

When I view the pagesource , the data-* attributes are correctly rendered for the model properties.

```
<div class="editor-label">
                <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

When I POST the form, only the password property displays the validation error. When I check the Model.IsValid, all the failed validations are in the collection...

So why, do only some of the validation errors display on the form after an attempted POST?

Comment: can you post the form code?

Comment: i dont see password field anywhere

Comment: I am only showing the fields that are not working - password is showing the validation correctly

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you added everything about the form ;)

My question though, is does it submit? You have the required filter on a number of fields but with no message (so it probably displays no errors, but does not submit).

Have you tried these:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

And (for the fields you want validated:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```